# Twitter Premium API Sandbox : Error Code 403

Tags: twitter

I am trying to grab data from Twitter through Premium API Sandbox.

I have built the 30-day Premium API Sandbox and the following is my code to send the request.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
r = api.request('tweets/search/30day/:test.json', {'q' : 'python') //test is my own label

for item in r:
     print(item['text'])
```

However, I keep receiving error code 403 like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Twitter_api_srch_full.py", line 11, in <module>
    for item in r:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 206, in __iter__
    return self.get_iterator()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 193, in get_iterator
    raise TwitterRequestError(self.response.status_code)
TwitterAPI.TwitterError.TwitterRequestError: Twitter request failed (403)
```

Do anyone know potential reasons to cause such error?

Thank you for your helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Search API's `q` parameter with the Premium API search. Use `query` instead, like this:

```
r = api.request('tweets/search/30day/:test', {'query' : 'python'})
```

Comment: I was using the sandbox for free so I thought its parameters should be the same with standard search API.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues in your code:

1. The label you're using should not be preceded with a colon, or end with `.json`
2. The 'q' parameter should be 'query'

There's a [sample](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/premium_search.py) in the TwitterAPI repo, but here's something working:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'

PRODUCT = '30day'
LABEL = 'development'

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), {'query' : 'python'}) 

for item in r:
     print(item['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) is not the official Python wrapper for both Twitter Premium and Enterprise APIs, I will hihgly suggest you to use [search-tweets-python](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python) as it is the [twitterdev](https://github.com/twitterdev) release.

So on, to install **search-tweets-python** you can do it through PyPi via the following command:

`python -m pip install searchtweets`

You can get more information on [searchtweets PyPi package](https://pypi.org/project/searchtweets/) on its latest version.

Once you install it, you need to create a **.yaml** file as described in https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python/blob/master/examples/credential_handling.rst that in your case, using the 30 day SandBox search, will look like this:

[image]

Once you create your `twitter_api_premium_credentials.yaml` file, you can start using the Premium Twitter API via Python, and the code in your case will be more or less like:

```
from searchtweets import load_credentials, gen_rule_payload, collect_results, ResultStream


premium_search_args = load_credentials("twitter_api_premium_credentials.yaml",
                                       yaml_key="search_tweets_premium_api",
                                       env_overwrite=False)

rule = gen_rule_payload("python lang:en", results_per_call=100)

rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
                  max_results=100,
                  max_pages=1,
                  **premium_search_args)

tweets = list(rs.stream())

[print(tweet.all_text, end='\n\n') for tweet in tweets[0:10]]
```

As you can see on the piece of code above, you are importing the functions you need to use in order to retrieve tweets, getting the bearer token with you credentials, generating the query or rule payload and retrieving the tweets.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: TwitterAPI, though not "official," is included in Twitter's list of 3rd party libraries. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html

Comment: @Jonas I did not say it is the official Python API wrapper, I just said that it is the twitterdev release! But thank you for clarifying it, it can be confusing!